# @react-native-async-storage/async-storage getItem is giving value as false

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to access react-native Async storage in a different file from where it has been set. In the same file where it is being set , i am able to get the value. but in the different file i am getting "false" as the value.
Any help would be greatly be appreciated.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

 const getData = async () => {
    console.log("fetching data from asyncstorage")
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');        << retuning false
      if(value !== null) {
        console.log(value);
        token.token=value;              
      }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
  }

const callfunction=()=>{
    getData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i was able to make it work,If somebody got a better solution please do post here,

As operation with AsyncStorage are happening in async manner, meaning the main thread will not wait for the function call to be coompleted, i found it best to call the function way before i needed it and keep it stored.
In order to acheive this i used a react hook "useEffect" this is similar to springboot alternative @PostConstruct, meaning "useEffect" will be called the moment you are navigate to the page. So the code looks something like this.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
const [token, setToken] = React.useState({
    token: "",
});

const getData = () => {
    console.log("fetching data from asyncstorage")
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken').then((value) => {
        console.log("token : "+ value);
        token.token=value;
    }).done();
}

useEffect(() => {  
    if(token.token=="")  
    {
        getData();
    }
});
```

If someone finds any good blog or video supporting this do post it here, also if my explanation, is deviating from technical aspect please help me understand it better.

Comment: There's a lot of info missing. what are you trying to achieve? what is `token` and what is `token.token`? show the full component and an explanation of what you are trying to do and you'll more community attention and feedback.

Comment: Yes correct, the `AsyncStorage.getItem` is async. Thanks for knowledge =)